# Problem with Qgis 3.22 windos 11 - attributes fields disappear and Asian symbols appear

Tags: attribute-table, vector, fields-attributes

Qgis versione 3.22 windos 11

I have this problem on Qgis 3.22 since a week already.
Everytime I try to create or edit a vector file I get this error. Everytime I save the vector attributes fields disappear and Asian symbols appear.
I already try to disintal and instal other versione but problem persist.
Someone help me plsenter image description here

[image]

---

I attach photos of the error. Hope someone can help me

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In practice, when I created a shapefiles and I go to add columns in the attribute table, these are auto-deleted and new columns are created. This makes me unable to use the attribute table because it deletes everything I put in it.

Comment: What are the vector file format ? (or does this affect all vector format). You seem to have some action defined (Azioni) does it happen without action ?

Comment: The files are polygonal shp files. "The action" appeared to me without my putting it on voluntarily. It all happened after exchanging files with a work colleague

Comment: You give to few information to really identify the problem (and we don't know what your colleague did...) but you can try to remove the action (on the layer properties go to the action tab), while you are in the layer properties you may check the data source encoding (in the source tab) as weird character are often caused by a wrong encoding selection.

Comment: you may also try to load the shapefile in a new qgis project using a new profile and tell us if the problem persist